# error: cannot access zza class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps

I am facing an exception in my application for location tracking. the exception is about zza class.

Here the code of my home activity.

```
package com.example.u.register;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.u.register.Model.Tracking;
import com.example.u.register.Model.User;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    DatabaseReference onlineRef, currentUserRef, counterRef, locations;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder> adapter;

    RecyclerView listOnline;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE= 7171;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST= 7172;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    private static long UPDATE_INTERVAL= 5000;
    private static long FASTEST_INTERVEL= 3000;
    private static float DISTANCE= 10;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        listOnline= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listOnline.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        listOnline.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Toolbar toolBar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolBar.setTitle("Online Users");
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

        locations= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Locations");
        onlineRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(".info/connected");
        counterRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("lastOnline");
        currentUserRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("lastOnline")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            if (checkPlayServices()){
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                createLocationRequest();
                displayLocation();
            }
        }

        setupSystem();

        updateList();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (checkPlayServices()){
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                        createLocationRequest();

                    }
                }
            }break;
        }
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return;
            }
            mLastLocation= LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null){
            locations.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .setValue(new Tracking(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                            String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()),
                            String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude())));

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't get the location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest= new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVEL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISTANCE);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    }

    private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient= new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This Device is not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void updateList() {

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(counterRef, User.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListOnlineViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User model) {
                holder.textemail.setText(model.getEmail());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ListOnlineViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view= LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);
                return new ListOnlineViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listOnline.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void setupSystem() {

        onlineRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)){
                    counterRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();
                    counterRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),"Online"));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        counterRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user= postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Log.d("Log", "" +user.getEmail() + " is "+user.getStatus());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_join:
                counterRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),"Online"));
                break;
            case R.id.action_logout:
                currentUserRef.removeValue();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation= location;
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        displayLocation();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,
                (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }
}
```

This is the app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.u.register"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

I hope someone would help me to find the mistake and resolve it.

Comment: Why you using `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` in multiple time in different version?

Comment: Which version of Gradle you have used currently?

Comment: I am using gradle-4.10.3

Comment: @FaysalAhmed when I use only one dependency of  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps` it does not sync correctly

Comment: Now I have edited dependencies by deleting 1 `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'` but facing the same problem...

Comment: Please keep the latest version of dependency. Would you please share project level build.gradle file ?

Comment: Firs of all really sorry for responding late to you....
here my project level build.gradle file

`buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`

Comment: Ok bro.... Either this will suitable or not.... bundle of thanks for ur effort :)

Comment: No it is not.... I've updated android studio to 3.3.1. After installation new updates I'll try it again

Comment: Its not working